# Reactor paginated web service calls

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor

I am using reactor in a spring project where I have to call a paginated api.
The api returns something like this :

```
{
  "last": false,
  "totalPages": 2,
  "totalElements": 4178,
  "sort": {
    "sorted": false,
    "unsorted": true
  },
  "first": false,
  "numberOfElements": 1178,
  "size": 3000,
  "number": 0
}
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is using webflux to call the server until last == true.

I can't figure our what would be the right way to do that.

What i have got so far is this :

```
Mono<UserInfo> firstUserInfo =  panelistService.getInactiveUserInfo(noOfDays, role, pageNo);


    Flux<User> listOfUsers = firstUserInfo.flatMap(fui ->{

        logger.info("ACCOUNT SERVICE - purgeCronJob - Getting first page of inactive panelists -  page {} total {} last {} panelists {}", pageNo,fui.getTotalNoOfPages(),fui.isLast(),fui.getUserContent().size()); 

        Mono<List<User>> firstListOfUsers = Mono.just(fui.getUserContent());

        if(fui.isLast()) {
            return firstListOfUsers;
        }

        pageNo++;
        int totalPageNo = fui.getTotalNoOfPages();

        for(int i = pageNo; i < totalPageNo; i++) {

            Mono<List<User>> lou = panelistService.getInactiveUserInfo(noOfDays, role, i).map(ui ->{
                logger.info("ACCOUNT SERVICE - purgeCronJob - Getting inactive panelists -  page {} total {} last {} panelists {}", pageNo,ui.getTotalNoOfPages(),ui.isLast(),ui.getUserContent().size()); 
                return ui.getUserContent();
            }); 
            firstListOfUsers.zipWith(lou);
        }

        return firstListOfUsers;

    }).flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);

    listOfUsers.subscribe();
```

So in stead of getting the last value , i build all the mono for each page and zip them all together .

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way and I hope this helps others. I have created a method that get the inactive accounts and recursively called that method. The difference is that now I am returning directly a Flux of Users, and that I Flux.merge my recursive calls.

```
Flux<User> getInactiveUserByPage(Integer noOfDays, String role, Integer pageNo){

    return  panelistService.getInactiveUserInfo(noOfDays, role, pageNo).flatMapMany(ui ->{

        logger.info("ACCOUNT SERVICE - getInactiveUserByPage - Getting inactive panelists -  page {} total {} last {} panelists {}", pageNo,ui.getTotalNoOfPages(),ui.isLast(),ui.getUserContent().size()); 

        Flux<User> users = Flux.fromIterable(ui.getUserContent());

        if(ui.isLast()) {
            return users;
        }

        Integer newPageNo  = pageNo+1;

        Flux<User> next =  getInactiveUserByPage(noOfDays, role, newPageNo).subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic()).mergeWith(users);

        return next;
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a flux depending on the totalPages count, having the noOfDays and role set somewhere outside, and getting the totalSize from a first request:

```
Flux.range(0,totalSize)
   .map(pageNo -> panelistService.getInactiveUserInfo(noOfDays, role, pageNo)...
```

Comment: How would you increase the pageNo as it should increase on each call, perhaps an atomic integer and in the map increase the value ?

Comment: The Flux.range emits the increments, and you can use them as shown. Did I understand your question correctly?